# Setting SeekBar progress without setting the thumb

Tags: android, progress-bar, seekbar

I would like to change the progress indication of the bar (the yellow filling stripe) without also moving the thumb. In my application the thumb indicates a constant threshold and the stripe (progress) indicates a measured value. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks,

smichak

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write you custom seekbar for that. I don't think there is any other way to do it.

Comment: And how do I do that? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Refer this, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html You can also have a look at the android.widget.ProgressBar.java and the android.widget.SeekBar.java source codes.